# Write a file without overwriting with python?

Tags: python, list, text, overwrite

```
lst = ['hello world', 'hi I am Josh']
```

I want to write two files, one containing lst[0] and the other lst[1].
This way, it does not work because the file comes overwritten.

```
for wd in lst:
   with open('hey.txt', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(wd)
```

How can i fix that code?

Comment: Why would you be able to have two different files with the same name at the same location? Think about what you're trying to do here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify different file names:

```
lst = ['hello world', 'hi I am Josh']
index = 0

for wd in lst:
   with open('hey%s.txt' % index, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(wd)
      index += 1
```

This will output "hello world" in hey0.txt and "hi I'm Josh" in hey1.txt

You can event replace the:

```
open('hey%s.txt' % index
```

part with:

```
open('hey%s.txt' % (index if index else '')
```

This way you'll have "hey.txt" and "hey1.txt" (it does not append the index if it equals 0)

Comment: very very useful!! I didn't know the "%" method, how does it work? Why we use %s? Thank you very much!

Comment: It replaces a part of the string with the arguments you pass to it. iirc, %s means 'use it as a string' (you can have some number formatting with this syntax). It is like if I had wrote 'hey' + str(index) + '.txt'. Some more explanations here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 3):

You could switch the order of your loops:

```
with open('hey.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for wd in lst:
        f.write(wd)
```

Or you could switch over to "append" mode:

```
for wd in lst:
    with open('hey.txt', 'ab') as f:
        f.write(wd)
```

Or write it all in one go:

```
with open('hey.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(lst))
```

Or write to two different files:

```
for j, wd in enumerate(lst):
    with open('hey_%i.txt' % j, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(wd)
```

Comment: I had forgotten the 'enumerate' while writing my answer. I find it cleaner than declaring an index variable the way I did :)